# Android: TabHost Replace fragment in tab with another

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, fragment-tab-host

I have a FragmentTabHost that contains 5 tabs. One of them loads a ListFragment. When an Item in the list is clicked I'd like to load a new fragment into the current tab. I can't seem to find out how to do this. The only thing I've managed to do is launch a whole new activity with the new content. How would I go about loading a new fragment into the active tab?

Comment: did you solve that?i have same issue..i am able to transaction to new fragment..but my tabhost is not showing

Answer (score 5):

In the onClick method of your list you can call the method in the activity with the following code that replaces the fragment (supposing android.R.id.tabcontent is the id of FrameLayout in FragmentTabHost):

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(android.R.id.tabcontent, new TabFragment());
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

Comment: is it possible that tabhost can be accessible in fragement where you make transaction?